# parallax scrolling issue, using stellar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a static site using parallax effect on it.I use stellar.js for parallax. Everything is working fine but when I open it in Safari then the problem begins, Its so buggy and not smooth at all. You can check it here-

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/126128285/empowered-marketing/index.html

Can anyone please give me the solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome you should look at the console and see that there are quite a few errors like:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
```

which basically means that you need to include jQuery on your page because it's required by Bootstrap.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

you've got "<" somewhere in your JavaScript code which shouldn't be there

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollspy'
```

you are trying to use a method which doesn't exist which could be a result of the previous two errors.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you tell me which jquery I need to include. Because I already added jquery but it still says to add jquery

Comment: You need to include jQuery before bootstrap.min.js